# How to use layout class in the fragment's onCreateView() method?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have res/layout/main_menu_layout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

    <sidekick.cpp.CMainMenuButton
        android:id="@+id/manualMainMenuButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/main_menu_button_manual_text" />

    <sidekick.cpp.CMainMenuButton
        android:id="@+id/editorMainMenuButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/main_menu_button_editor_text" />

    <sidekick.cpp.CMainMenuButton
        android:id="@+id/exitMainMenuButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/main_menu_button_exit_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This layout is used in the class below:

> ```
> package sidekick.cpp;
>
> import android.widget.*;
> import android.content.*;
> import android.view.*;
>
> public class CMainMenuLayout extends LinearLayout {
>
> public CMainMenuLayout(Context context) {
>         super(context);
>         this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
>         View view =  LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
>         R.layout.main_menu_layout, null);
>
>         this.addView(view);
>
>         } }
> ```

Now I want to use the layout in a fragment. If I use the layout's ID (`R.layout.main_menu_layout`) in `onCreateView()`  then the below code seems to work:

```
public class CMainMenuFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener  {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu_layout, container, false);

    }
...

    }
```

But I need to use the CMainLayout class, not `R.layout.main_menu_layout`. The code below seems to work too but is it correct?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        CMainMenuLayout layout = new CMainMenuLayout(this.getContext());
        return layout;
}
```

Comment: yes it is correct, as parent of `CMainMenuLayout`-->`LinearLayout` which extends `ViewGroup` further which extends---> `View` so basically you can return layout from `onCreateView`. Now point remain whether is it the optimized way to do?

Comment: @Shadow Droid, Thank you for quick explanation! I have to use onCreateView like this because it is in my classroom assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can inflate xml layout in `CMainMenuLayout` directly

```
public CMainMenuLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
    LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_menu_layout, this, true);
}
```

then use `CMainMenuLayout` class in xml for `CMainMenuFragment`. For example
 *res/layout/main_fragment_layout.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <sidekick.cpp.CMainMenuLayout 
        android:id="@+id/mainMenuLayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and in `CMainMenuFragment`

```
public class CMainMenuFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener  {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_menu_fragment, container, false);

}
    ...

}
```